# How does the non-believer profit from the Bhagavat Gita?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, other-religions

Why is that in the Bhagavat Gita, it is said that to truly understand it, one needs to completely surrender to Krishna and accept him as the only Supreme God?

If a non-believer or a person of different faith tries to study the Gita, isn't it supposed to enlighten him instead of stating the above and giving him a negative vibe?

Comment: Where does the Bhagavad Gita say that you need to completely surrender to Vishnu in order to understand it?  It does say that if you completely surrender to Vishnu, then you'll be delivered from all your sins; see here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7971/36 But I don't know of any verse that says that surrender is a prerequisite for understanding the Gita.

Comment: `Lord Sri Krsna is the Supreme Personality of Godhead, at least theoretically, according to the statements of Bhagavad-gita or the statements of Arjuna, the person who is trying to understand the Bhagavad-gita. We should therefore at least theoretically accept Sri Krsna as the Supreme Personality of Godhead, and with that submissive spirit we can understand the Bhagavad-gita. Unless one reads the Bhagavad-gita in a submissive spirit, it is very difficult to understand Bhagavad-gita because it is a great mystery.`

Comment: One should believe in God and should see Krishna as God to  understand it. Else who would listen to his philosophies if he wasn't God. How can non believers believe in teachings of some King (who had higher IQ) with earnest devotion? Bhagavad Gita wouldn't be such an important text if He wasn't  God. It would be some random text. BG is short summary of Vedas and Dharma.

Comment: @AnilKumar I agree. But shouldn't the teachings themselves make the non-beliver believe that the contents of BG are the truth? If you don't believe, you don't understand. If you don't understand, you wont believe? How to overcome this?

Comment: i think you have BG by ISKCON. They highlight Krishna more in that book. You can read other commentaries from this site.  http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/

Comment: @VarunRao That's not a quote from the Bhagava Gita, it's a quote from the ISKCON introduction to the Bhagavas Gita: http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/introduction

Comment: @VarunRao I think it's certainly possible for a non-believer to read the Bhagavas Gita and then become a believer.

Comment: Yes. True. It is from ISKCON. My friend stressed the point that I should read the unadulterated  GITA that has been passed down from an official line of Gurus. That is why I am reading the one from ISKCON

Comment: I agree with @AnilKumar, the ISKCON commentary is not the best.  What I'd recommend is using this website which gives a bunch of different commentaries on the Bhagavas Gita, so you can compare them and judge for yourself which one is the best: http://www.bhagavad-gita.us  (I prefer Ramanujachara's commentary, as I'm a Sri Vaishnava.). By the way, these commentaries also come from people who were part of some line of Gurus.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thank. I will refer http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/ and the vedabase.com/en/bg/introduction. I'll find out to myself

Comment: I recommend that you use http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/ rather than http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/ The second one has very bad translations of the different commentaries. http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/, the one that has a picture of a tree, is much better.

Comment: Late Sambhu Mitra, a renowned writer and actor was atheist but respected Gita highly.

Comment: It seems to me the main help that the Gita might offer to the non-believer is that by reading it they may become one, and even a non-believer might understand what is said up to the point that their understanding may be useful. I know best the commentary by Krishna Prem and would say it has much to offer the non-believer. It seems inevitable, however, that nobody could understand it fully without transcending the need to believe or not-believe. If we merely believe the Gita then we will not be quite sure what we believe. I wish more non-believing philosophers of mind would read it.

Comment: @Peter J yes, Krishnaprem's comnentary was available for free download and I got it. It is really beautiful.Thanks for naming that great saint.

Comment: @Partha - So glad you got it, and for free. Beautiful is a good word for it. It's so good I'm lost for words.  .

Answer (score 2):

Well there are many ways even a non believer can get benefited.

There are many management principles in gita, some of the samples are:

> कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन।
>   
> मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि।।2.47।।
>
> Meaning: But thou hast only the right to work, but none to the fruit thereof. Let not then the fruit of thy action be thy motive; nor yet be thou enamored of inaction.

It gives how we can get strayed away.

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंसः सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते।
>   
> सङ्गात् संजायते कामः कामात्क्रोधोऽभिजायते।।2.62।।
>
> क्रोधाद्भवति संमोहः संमोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रमः।
>   
> स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति।।2.63।।
>
> Meaning: When a man dwells on the objects of sense, he creates an attraction for them; attraction develops into desire, and desire breeds anger. (2.62)
>   
>  Anger induces delusion; delusion, loss of memory; through loss of memory, reason is shattered; and loss of reason leads to destruction. (2.63)
>
> इन्द्रियाणां हि चरतां यन्मनोऽनुविधीयते।
>   
> तदस्य हरति प्रज्ञां वायुर्नावमिवाम्भसि।।2.67।।
>
> Meaning: As a ship at sea is tossed by the tempest, so the reason is carried away by the mind when preyed upon by straying senses.

Thus by carefully understanding these verses & applying in our life, any one can get benefited.

Answer (score -2):

It can be said that the following verses from Bhakthi Yoga, Chapter 12, of Bhagvad Gita, negate the presumption in the said question.

> 6
>   Whosoever hath faith in Me /
>   And leans on Me heart ’n soul -
>
> 7
>   Him I help to cross over /
>   Ocean vast of births ’n deaths.
>
> 8
>   If thou develop faith in Me / 
>   Take for granted I take thee.
>
> 9
>   Were thee to fail develop faith /
>   It’s not thou reached blind alley, /
>   Ever Me having in thy mind /
>   Practice lets thee turn the bend.
>
> 10
>   If thou feel that’s hard as well /
>   Indulge then in deeds Me please.
>
> 11
>   If thou find that difficult too /
>   Give thyself to Me Supreme /
>   Act then with thy subdued mind /
>   With no thought for what follows.
>
> 12
>   Scores thought over mere roting /
>   Betters meditation awareness too /
>   What helps man to find moorings /
>   Are acts his with no axe to grind.

Excerpted from the free ebook "Bhagvad-Gita: Treatise of Self-help" available in PDF at  [Project Gutenberg self-Publishing Press](http://self.gutenberg.org/eBooks/WPLBN0002097652-Bhagvad-Gita-Treatise-of-Self-Help-by-Murthy-B-S-.aspx?)

Comment: I see it as sharing information and don't see as self-promotion as this work is already in the public domain to much acclaim.